# Using curly braces in an array reduce function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

If `fn3` is substituted for `fn2` in this example running in node 9.5.0 the `console.log(totalUpvotes)` will log `undefined`.  IIUC the result should be the same (92)?

```
    const posts = [{id: 1, upVotes: 2}, {id:2, upVotes: 89}, {id: 3, upVotes: 1}];

    const fn2 = (totalUpvotes, currentPost) => totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes;

    const fn3 = (totalUpvotes, currentPost) => {totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes}

    const totalUpvotes = posts.reduce(fn2, 0);

    console.log(totalUpvotes);
```

Comment: `{...}` is like having a Normal Function *without* a `return`.

Comment: @georg Why is that so? Does `{...}` have a value? Or is this a special grammar rule (or bypassing a grammar rule)?

Comment: This is not a strict duplicate of that .. the OP is not trying to return an *object* from a literal. However, the explanation is related.

Comment: `(x, y) => expr` is equivalent to `(x, y) => { return expr; }`.

Comment: "Both functions (fn2, fn3) compile to the same thing on es6 console" - no, look again, one has `return`, the other doesn't.

Comment: Ah got it - missed the return function is es console https://es6console.com/jdmbr6sq/

Comment: `{ totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes }` is equivalent to `{ totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes; return undefined; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the runtime sees that the curly braces are omitted, it includes the `return` statement for you.  See  example below, as well as [Arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> ```
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
> // equivalent to: => { return expression; }
> ```

Note the equivalency of the form that *takes an expression* with the form that *takes statements*. The form that takes statements will always result in an undefined return value unless terminating with an appropriate `return`.

JavaScript does not have an "implicit statement block value"; with the exclusion of object-literals, {} braces always introduce *some* form of a non-expression.

See this example:

[es6 console](https://es6console.com/jdmbr6sq/)

Here it is for the impatient:

```
    "use strict";

    var fn2 = function fn2(totalUpvotes, currentPost) {
      return totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes;
    };

    var fn3 = function fn3(totalUpvotes, currentPost) {
      totalUpvotes + currentPost.upVotes;
    };
```